# How to set the datacontext of a user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm writing an application in WPF, using the MVVm toolkit and have problems with hooking up the viewmodel and view.

The model is created with ado.net entity framework.

The viewmodel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        private Models.Customer customer;
        //constructor
        private ObservableCollection<Models.Customer> _customer = new ObservableCollection<Models.Customer>();
        public ObservableCollection<Models.Customer> AllCustomers
        {
            get { return _customer; }

        }
        private Models.Customer _selectedItem;
        public Models.Customer SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }

        }
        public void LoadCustomers()
        {
            List<Models.Customer> list = DataAccessLayer.getcustomers();
            foreach (Models.Customer customer in list)
            {
                this._customer.Add(customer);
            }
            }
        }
```

And the view (no code behind at the moment):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Customers.Customer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:Customers.ViewModels"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" >

    <Grid>
        <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

        </toolkit:DataGrid>

        <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Orders}">

        </toolkit:DataGrid>



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And dataaccesslayer class:

```
 class DataAccessLayer
    {
        public List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        public static List<Customer> getcustomers()
        {
            entities db = new entities();

            var customers = from c in db.Customer.Include("Orders")
                           select c;
            return customers.ToList();
        }


    }
```

The problem is that no data is displayed simply because the data context is not set. I tried to do it in a code-behind but is did not work. I would prefer to do it in a xaml file anyway. Another problem is with the SelectedItem binding - the code is never used.

Comment: In your code you have an AllCustomers property on your View Model but you are binding to Customers.

Comment: I was cleaning the code slightly and made a typo. The binding in the working code is of course correct.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is using the MVVM paradigm, I would instance your ViewModel in the constructor for the View.  My View/ViewModels typically follow this sequence of events:

1. View is instanced
2. View constructor instances ViewModel
3. ViewModel initializes
4. ViewModel runs data getting procedures(separate thread)
5. ViewModel calls OnPropertyChanged("") to alert View that something has changed; check everything

My ViewModel is instanced from the XAML codebehind (sorry this is in VB.NET, have not gotten around to learning C# well enough to trust myself with it):

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Me.DataContext = New EditShipmentViewModel(Me) 'pass the view in to set as a View variable
    Me.InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

Initially I hoped to have something like

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Local:EditShipmentViewModel>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

But that did not work out like I wanted it to.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: This is the opposite of MVVM.

Comment: @EdPlunkett You are totally welcome to post an answer.

Comment: This is one of the most common anti-patterns in WPF. You shouldn't be encouraging beginners to use anti-patterns that will cause them trouble and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606803/silverlight-setting-datacontext-in-xaml-rather-than-in-constructor) what you're looking for?

Comment: yes and no. I need to somehow call the method getcustomers(). Should I do it in a viewmodel constructor? Doesn't seem very good.

Comment: Personally I would have the ViewModel call getcustomers() in the constructor.  What do you feel is not good about it?  When the view renders it will create a new instance of the ViewModel and at that point you want the data to be retrieved, so it makes sense for the constructor to do it.

Comment: What about the xaml construction <UserControl.DataContext> in Resources?

Comment: The only major issue with declaring the object in the XAML is that any error thrown during the VM construction, will be eaten by a XAML parsing error. We have switched off to using a DI like MEF to have inject the VM into the View's DataContext at Load. OnLoad can fire multiple times so make sure you short circuit it with an _isLoaded field or something of the like.

Comment: Yes that's a better solution to use DI for sure.  Nice comment!

Answer (score 0):

I set my viewmodel datacontext the same way I observed Blend4 to. That is, if my viewmodel is called MainViewModel, I reference it in the view like:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModelDataSource" />
 </UserControl.Resources>

 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModelDataSource}}">
    ...view xaml stuff

 </Grid>
```

also, if you're loading data from a database in the constructor of your viewmodel, don't forget to add a helper method around it like:

```
  if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
        {
             myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Blah>(something);
        }
```

so that visual studio/Blend4 doesn't crash trying to retrieve the data from the database connection in the Designer. I personally load data in the constructor quite often, just because I need it right away, and for it to be cached in memory from startup.

:)