# bind item's children control in ItemsControl wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, itemscontrol

i am binding an ItemsControl to a list, but in item template there is a control which is not binding by current dataSource, i want to bind it with another dataSource.

but i am stuck at accessing that control

my ItemsControl's dataTemplate is--->

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemRequesterList" IsTabStop="False">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Name="ItemReqTemplate">
             <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="requested on"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock> //<---this control, i 
                                               //    want to bind with another dataSource
             </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate>
```

so how can i access this control, which is lie in each item ?

Comment: What is the relationship between the item in the 1st `DataSource` and the 2nd `DataSource`?? Index??

Comment: Where is the second data source? Is it static, part of parent DataContext, another control's DataContext?

Comment: @sa_ddam213: no relation between 1st & 2nd dataSource.

Comment: @Toni Petrina: is it matters where the 2nd dataSource ?

Comment: The answer depends on where the second data source is. There is no single solution to this problem.

Comment: Use relative source and bind it to a controls DataContext.FirstName.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the DataContext of that control to some static resource, for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource myOtherContext}"></TextBlock>
```

See the following:

[Silverlight - Setting DataContext in XAML rather than in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606803/silverlight-setting-datacontext-in-xaml-rather-than-in-constructor)